# A scientist catches 8 butterflies I

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A scientist catches $8$ butterflies, each of which may appear in one of $4$ different colors:

- White
- Brown
- Red
- Black

**What is the probability that the last butterfly caught is the second white**?

The optional answers are:

- $0.078$
- $0.089$
- $0.311$
- $0.356$

My attempts:

We have **equal space** and independent events.

Every butterfly can be in any of the $4$ different colors.

The probability of catching a butterfly with a specific color is $\frac14$.

Therefore, using Binomial distribution, the answer should be $\binom71\cdot\left(\frac14\right)^1\cdot\left(\frac34\right)^6\cdot\left(\frac14\right)$.

For the first $7$ multiplied with $\frac14$ for the last like geometric distribution $=0.07786$?

Comment: What do you mean "second white"???

Comment: Hint:  of the first seven you need exactly one to be white, and then you need number eight to be white.  Two independent events, so their probabilities just multiply.

Comment: It means catches 8 butterflies one random of the first seven is white the last one also white , the space is 4^8 ,every butterfly has for choices

Comment: @barakmanos: 8 butterflies, 4 colours $\implies$ each colour represented by 2 butterflies. "second white" = the second white butterfly (the counting reflects the order in which they are caught).

Comment: "put on hold as off-topic" ,it is my first post at this site so please try to take this into consideration ,I was asked to post my solutions ,and I did add them later ,I don't know what is the problem now??I'm not a lazy guy ,I'm very clever but sometimes I face difficulties and need help.

Comment: In this question everything was ok,also I've got 19 good answers out of 20 questions

Answer (score 2):

The total number of sequences is $4^8$.

The number of sequences containing $2$ white butterflies with one of them at the end is:

- Put the second white butterfly at the $8$th place
- Choose $1$ out of the remaining $7$ places for the first white: $\binom71$
- In the remaining $6$ places, choose any of the remaining $3$ colors: $3^6$

Hence the probability is $\frac{\binom71\cdot3^6}{4^8}\approx0.078$.

Comment: good!! another similar question the same experiment ,what is the probability that the fifth butterfly is the first red??

Comment: @abdcom: Post it as a separate question (and try to include your own attempts this time, this is not a 'do my homework for free' service).

Comment: @abdcom: Showing your work does not influence one's solution. If anything, people here will point out certain things in your on method (e.g., correctness, efficiency, etc).

Comment: @abdcom: Please post it **within** the question, it is hardly readable in the comment (and a lot more appropriate in the question, especially since you haven't provided any of those details up there). Also, please you LaTex for mathematical notation.

Comment: the second I have two different solution :                                            (3/4)^4*(1/4)=0.0791        or c(4,3)3^4/4^5=0.3164      the answes are       a 0.25  b 0.079  c 0.396  d 0.316

Comment: @abdcom: What does "c(3/4)" mean????? Please share all your doubts **WITHIN THE QUESTION**, and please **USE LATEX** (I don't know how else to explain this).

Comment: never mind  may be latter I'll download a LATEX PROGRAM ,I've added everything to the main Question and corrected the "c(1/4)" it should be *(1/4) ,simply used distributions with p=1/4 as random variables ???thank you for your help ,I need the second question in order to be calm .

Comment: @abdcom: I'm afraid your question is unreadable now (at least IMO).

Comment: @abdcom: OMG, it's even worse now. Let me do it for you, then you can edit it and understand what the LaTex notations are (and how easy it is to use them without any designated application).

Comment: I can't chat because I'm new don't have reputation ,only tell what is the write answer for the second question 0.316 or 0.079 ??